# FX & DX Lenses on DX Body

Tags: lens, nikon, focal-length, cropped-sensor, crop-factor

If I use a 50mm prime FX lens on a FX camera, I will get 50mm. If I use a 50mm prime FX lens on a DX camera, I'll get 75mm (assuming 1.5x crop factor).

Now, **if I use a 50mm prime DX lens on a DX camera, do I get 50mm or 75mm?** In other words, does a 50mm prime DX lens already account for the crop factor? Does the multiple only exist for a FX lens on a DX camera?

Note that I'm asking about putting FX and DX lenses on a DX body - not putting them on a FX body. I read [this article](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7824/does-a-nikon-dx-lens-on-a-fx-camera-get-subjected-to-the-1-5x-crop-factor) but it discusses putting DX lenses on an FX body. I just want to know if 50mm is 50mm whether it's DX or FX lens; and if I put that on a FX body it'll be 50mm and DX body it'll be 75mm.

To further clarify....

1. I take a picture with a 50mm FX prime on a FX body
2. I take a picture with a 50mm FX prime on a DX body
3. I take a picture with a 50mm DX prime on a DX body

Photos 1 and 2 will be different - 2 will be zoomed by 1.5x. Will 1 and 3 be the same or will 2 and 3 be the same?

Comment: Sorry, that possible duplicate is the opposite. But there are other existing questions which cover this....

Comment: Perhaps this one? https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38899/why-do-full-frame-lenses-and-crop-body-lenses-exhibit-the-same-crop-factor-when

Comment: Kind of mattdm, but not quite.. I couldn't find a clear answer in that thread differentiating between FX and DX lenses even though there was a thorough discussion of crop factor calcs. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @tryan 50mm is 50mm. On a 1.5X crop body a 50mm lens will give an ≈23° diagonal angle of view. It doesn't matter if it is a DX or FX lens when you are using a DX body.

Comment: Related: [Why do my 50mm APS-C and 50mm FF lenses have the same angle-of-view on my APS-C camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/89853/15871) The only answer to that question (also marked as a duplicate) has links to 13 other questions here among the near countless examples that ask the same thing here.

Comment: [Here's a link](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/38899?sort=votes) to 31 questions on the same subject.

Comment: I think maybe [
Does my crop sensor camera actually turn my lenses into a longer focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11338/does-my-crop-sensor-camera-actually-turn-my-lenses-into-a-longer-focal-length) covers this most closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lenses are labeled with their actual focal length. The concept of "equivalence" or "crop factor" only exists to help compare between different formats. For your examples, only example 1 has a wider field of view. The DX camera doesn't care that the lens happens to have a bigger image circle.

We have literally dozens of questions along these lines. Some of the most helpful in your particular case are:

- [Does my crop sensor camera actually turn my lenses into a longer focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11338/does-my-crop-sensor-camera-actually-turn-my-lenses-into-a-longer-focal-length)
- [What is crop factor and how does it relate to focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/139/what-is-crop-factor-and-how-does-it-relate-to-focal-length)
- [What is "angle of view" in photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5917/what-is-angle-of-view-in-photography)
- [Why do Full Frame lenses and crop body lenses exhibit the same crop factor when used on a crop body camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38899/why-do-full-frame-lenses-and-crop-body-lenses-exhibit-the-same-crop-factor-when)
- [Does an APS-C lens label itself with effective or true focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/75932/does-an-aps-c-lens-label-itself-with-effective-or-true-focal-length)

Comment: *Dozens?* Don'tcha' mean *hundreds?*